# Angular5: async/await returns promise but not value

Tags: promise, async-await, angular5

Seems like fundamental asynchronous implementation but I am unable to obtain a value from Angular5 service. Below is the service method:

```
async getEmployees() {
    return await this.http.get<Employee[]>('...')
        .pipe(
            map(employees => {
                const directory = [];
                employees.forEach(employee => {
                    directory.push({
                        firstName: employee.firstName,
                        lastName: employee.lastName,
                        phone: employee.phone,
                        email: employee.email,
                        city: employee.address.city,
                        avatar: employee.avatar
                    });
                });
                return directory;
            }),
            toArray()
        )
        .toPromise();
}
```

Here is how I am calling the service method above in my component:

```
export class StarmarkDirectoryComponent implements OnInit {

  public employees: any = [];
    private employeeService: StarmarkEmployeeService;

  constructor(employeeService: StarmarkEmployeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.employees = await this.employeeService.getEmployees();
  }

}
```

And here is the template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="city" class="form-control">
      <option value="">FILTER BY CITY NAME</option>
      <option *ngFor="let employee of employees; let a = index">
      {{ employee.city }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
<pre>
  {{ employees | json }}
</pre>
```

The employees renders as JSON within `<pre>` tag. However, I need to iterate in my template but don't understand how I need to obtain my value. I *am* able to obtain my return value using `{{ employees | json }}` however I cannot use `*ngFor` to iterate

Comment: When you use angular forget the promises, use observables of Rxjs, you can look at this link to know more, https://www.learnrxjs.io/ . In this case remove async/await, return observable and subscribe. And `employees.forEach` remove in favor of `employees.reduce((directory, employee) => directory, [])` with same logic, change `push` to `concat`. I hope to help

Comment: That is the expected behavior. An `async` function returns a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: The issue is that I am able to obtain my return value using `{{ employees | json }}` however I cannot use `*ngFor` to iterate? I don't understand why?

Comment: @botika Thanks for the website

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Shouldn't `employees` be populated with return value of `getEmployees()` so I may subsequently use it within `*ngFor`. Should I be return something different?

Comment: @MichaelNiño can you update with the exact problem you are having? You just state that you are unable to use it in `*ngFor`. Can you also provide what the result looks like when you use the `json` pipe?

Comment: Apparently the `*ngFor` is receiving an empty `employees` and thus has nothing to iterate over however `{{ employees | json }}` renders the JSON representation of `employees` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, when I remove the `toArray()` from the `pipe()` it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be subscribe for getEmployee method. 
Ex.

```
this.employeeService.getEmployee()
     .subscribe((data)=>{
            this.employees = data;
      });
```

"Pls excuse for any typo error"

Comment: The `getEmployee()` method returns a promise and cannot use `subscribe()`.